# In Codeigniter fetching symbols from URI intepret differently

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am fetching '$' symbol from uri.
And I have already added $ in permitted_uri_chars in config file.
Later I am fetching data from database using that uri string.
issue can be seen from below example.

MY Url is like this ....

```
.....com/search/shirt/$
```

My Example code is this ...

```
echo $this->uri->segment('3');
echo "<br>";
var_dump($this->uri->segment('3'));
echo "<br>";
$dol_sign = '$';
echo $dol_sign;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($dol_sign);
```

MY Output of above code is this ...

```
$
string(5) "$"
$
string(1) "$"
```

it is taking segment as differently. that is why i m having issue in fetching data from DB matching with URI segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sign is an HTML encoded entity - if you see the source of the page you'll see `&amp;` instead of a simple `&`.

You can use the PHP [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function to decode it into the normal character, or test against it.